# How to guarantee an AWS SNS deleteEndpoint has been deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

How can I ensure that my SNS application endpoint is safely deleted before creating a new one with the same token? I have a delete method with a ProgressListner, however when I check for the deleted endpoint it still exists for a very short time.

I expected that on receiving the CLIENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS_EVENT that the delete was 100% done. I am using AmazonSNSClient not AmazonSNSAsyncClient

```
public void deleteEndpoint(final String applicationArn, final String token) {
    LOG.fine(String.format("Deleting endpoint by token for appArn=%s, token=%s", applicationArn, token));
    Endpoint endpoint = findEndpointByToken(applicationArn, token);
    if (endpoint != null) {

      DeleteEndpointRequest der = new DeleteEndpointRequest().withEndpointArn(endpoint.getEndpointArn());

      der.withGeneralProgressListener(new ProgressListener() {
        public void progressChanged(ProgressEvent event) {
          ProgressEventType eventType = event.getEventType();
          System.out.println(eventType);
          if (eventType.equals(ProgressEventType.CLIENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS_EVENT)) {
            Endpoint exists = findEndpointByToken(applicationArn, token);
            //This I expect this to be null but its only null after a few seconds 

          }
        }
      });

      LOG.info(String.format("Deleted endpoint by token for appArn=%s, token=%s", applicationArn, token));
    }
  }
```

The output of the events are

```
  CLIENT_REQUEST_STARTED_EVENT 
  HTTP_REQUEST_STARTED_EVENT
  HTTP_REQUEST_COMPLETED_EVENT 
  RESPONSE_CONTENT_LENGTH_EVENT
  HTTP_RESPONSE_STARTED_EVENT 
  RESPONSE_BYTE_TRANSFER_EVENT
  HTTP_RESPONSE_COMPLETED_EVENT 
  CLIENT_REQUEST_SUCCESS_EVENT
```

Comment: I see you creating a `DeleteEndpointRequest` object, but I don't see you passing it to `AmazonSNSClient.deleteEndpoint()` anywhere. I don't even see you using AmazonSNSClient anywhere in the code in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SNS is a large, scalable, distributed system, and with some operations, in systems like that, there's a bit of an uncertainty phenomenon, where something being deleted both still exists and no longer exists, simultaneously, as the deletion request is propagating through the system.

While the following statement does not directly prove that the above assertion applies to the action you're taking, it's a strong indicator:

> This action is idempotent.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_DeleteEndpoint.html

Idempotent actions can be repeated without the result changing (like adding 0 to an integer).  Essentially, if the action is idempotent as documented, then the success response doesn't mean "it has been deleted," it means "you are authorized to delete this, and it will be deleted, if it hasn't been already."

So, your workaround will be to poll in a loop with an exponential backoff timer until you get the expected null result, if you need to know that it's really gone before proceeding.  This does not actually guarantee that it will be fully gone system-wide, so it's possible that you could still have a conflict, though less likely.

"Guarantee" is a difficult proposition with distributed systems unless they have immediate consistency for all actions, which is often not the case, because immediate consistency often is at odds with scalability.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that in the distributed nature of AWS it's difficult to be sure when it's been deleted from all nodes/hosts etc, however I thought the ProgressListener would allow one to more accurately know when the item was successfully deleted. I did eventually have to do a timed repeat check to see if it was deleted before creating a new one and it can be as long as 10 seconds.